# How to make a fixed-position element inside a clip-path parent stay above all elements?

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/joshuajazleung/pen/YxvgVj

```
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>

<div></div>

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div:first-child {
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

I don't know what, but the fixed-position element stays behind the second div if its parent has the clip-path property. How can I make it stay above all elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a fixed-position element inside a clip-path parent stay above all elements, because clip-path make a new layer, such as you can't use a fixed-position element inside a transform parent.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m1sswtbd/) what you are looking for? I just made some changes in your html..

```
<div>
</div>
<span>Hello</span>
<div>
</div>
```